# SQL function to return only student grades below 2.5

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want this SQL report to return lastfirst, grade_level, course_number and grade, only when the grade is below 2.5.

The report I'm getting back is a row for each student's courses (7 per student) for each grade that student has below a 2.5.

When I remove the Where pg.grade <=2.5 then the all 7 student courses appear 7 times each. With replaced grades.

Ex. Student A has two grades below 2.5 (1 with a 2.5 / and 1 with a 2.1) In the first list of 7 courses the student's grade of 2.5 is repeated among all courses. The second list of 7 courses has the student grade of 2.1 listed across all 7 courses.

In this report student's grades are being replaced a grade that is below 2.5.

Student A has a 3.5 in 1001ENG but the report is assigning a grade of 2.5 and 2.1 to the student's English grade.

In the 2nd example

1001ENG is repeated 7 times - reflecting the English grade in one instance and the other six grades in others.

What am I doing incorrectly?

SQL Query

```
SELECT s.lastfirst, s.grade_level, cc.course_number, pg.grade
FROM students s
JOIN cc 
ON s.id = cc.studentid
JOIN pgfinalgrades pg
ON s.id = pg.studentid
WHERE pg.grade <='2.5'
AND s.schoolid=1
AND s.enroll_status=0
AND cc.termid>=3300
AND cc.course_number <>'OH9' 
AND cc.course_number <>'OH10'
AND cc.course_number <>'OH11'
AND cc.course_number <>'OH12'
AND cc.course_number <>'ASSEM'
AND cc.course_number <>'HR'
AND cc.course_number <>'Lunch'
AND pg.finalgradename = 'F1'
ORDER BY s.grade_level, s.lastfirst`
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlrB8.png)`

Comment: We don't have your tables. Does `pg` have a course number column that should be included as a join condition maybe? A [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: Beautiful, that fixed it. I changed the second Join to the tables cc and pg, and added a section ID join.

FROM students s
JOIN cc 
ON s.id = cc.studentid
JOIN pgfinalgrades pg
ON (cc.studentid = pg.studentid and cc.sectionID = pg.sectionid)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole solved it the other day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a courseTable that contains schoolid,courseNumber,studentid while  pgfinalgrades that also contains the schoolid,courseNumber,grade, studentID. Last assuming your students table only has demographics information related to the student.

```
SELECT s.lastfirst
, s.grade_level
, c.course_number
, g.grade
FROM students as s
INNER JOIN courses as c
ON s.schoolid = c.schoolid
s.id = c.studentid
INNER JOIN pgfinalgrades as g
ON c.schoolid = g.schoolid
and c.courseNumber = g.courseNumber
and c.studentid = g.studentid
WHERE pg.grade <='2.5'
AND s.enroll_status=0
AND c.termid>=3300
AND c.course_number not in ('OH9','OH10','OH11','OH12','ASSEM','HR','Lunch','F1')
ORDER BY s.grade_level, s.lastfirst
```

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole solved it, the other day.